# ESP12F, cant get a relay to work with data from dht11

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

i've been trying to build a system that detects in one room of the house the temperature using an esp8266 and a dht11 sensor, this esp sends the data to a webserver while the ESP12F grabs this data and should turn the relay on when a certain value is reached, however i can't get the relay to work, as soon as i upload the code, the led on the module turns but not at its full power, i tried with another code to see if it was just a faulty relay, but it works perfectly with the same connections. The code from the client side of the system is below:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include "ESP8266HTTPClient.h"
#include "WiFiClient.h"

#include "ESP8266WiFiMulti.h"
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

const char* ssid = "*******";
const char* password = "********";

//Your IP address or domain name with URL path
const char* serverNameTemp = "http://192.168.1.188/temperature";
const char* serverNameHumi = "http://192.168.1.188/humidity";
const char* serverNamePres = "http://192.168.1.188/pressure";

#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_SSD1306.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

String temperature;
String humidity;
String pressure;

const int relay = 5;

float temp_int = temperature.toFloat();


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 2000; 

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
pinMode(relay,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(relay,LOW);

  // Address 0x3C for 128x64, you might need to change this value (use an I2C scanner)
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  int int_temp = temperature.toFloat();

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP(ssid, password);
  while((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) { 
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
     // Check WiFi connection status
    if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
      int int_temp = temperature.toFloat();
      temperature = httpGETRequest(serverNameTemp);
      humidity = httpGETRequest(serverNameHumi);
      pressure = httpGETRequest(serverNamePres);
      if(int_temp < 26){
        digitalWrite(relay,LOW);
      }
     else if (int_temp > 26){
      digitalWrite(relay,HIGH);
     }

      Serial.println("Temperature: " + temperature + " *C - Humidity: " + humidity + " % - Pressure: " + pressure + " hPa");
      Serial.println(int_temp);
      Serial.println(temperature.toFloat());
      display.clearDisplay();

      // display temperature
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setCursor(0,0);
      display.print("T: ");
      display.print(temperature);
      display.print(" ");
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.cp437(true);
      display.write(248);
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.print("C");

      // display humidity
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setCursor(0, 25);
      display.print("H: ");
      display.print(humidity);
      display.print(" %"); 

      // display pressure
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setCursor(0, 50);
      display.print("P:");
      display.print(pressure);
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.setCursor(110, 56);
      display.print("hPa");

      display.display();

      // save the last HTTP GET Request
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
  }
}

String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  WiFiClient client;
  HTTPClient http;

  // Your IP address with path or Domain name with URL path 
  http.begin(client, serverName);

  // Send HTTP POST request
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();

  String payload = "--"; 

  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = http.getString();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();

  return payload;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the value is for `int int_temp = temperature.toFloat()` at your setup(), then again with `int int_temp = temperature.toFloat()` even before calling the `httpGETRequst()` function to get the temperature String?

Comment: note that  `int int_temp = temperature.toFloat();` doesn't make too much sense. Do you want a float or an int value. Why not use toInt()  or a float variable?

Comment: Yeah i noticed this error, i corrected it to output just an int value because i dont need that much precision, still the error with the relay is what concerns me.

Comment: Let me guess. You power relay from 5V and when you set output to LOW then led on module shines at full power. This is hardware issue with 5V relays which have P-N-P transistors so to switch relay coil completely OFF you need to set voltage to 5V but ESP can't provide it. [So you either need to use level shifter or use different kind of relay.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213051/how-do-i-use-a-5v-relay-with-a-3-3v-arduino-pro-mini)